# Can we remove bundled JRE from an install4j exe after install?

Tags: install4j

Is it possible to remove the bundled JRE *after* an install?

I tried simply deleting the '${installer:sys.installationDir}/jre' folder, but then the launcher fails to run.  Is it possible to have this fall back to looking for an appropriate system JRE?

Answer (score 0):

In the media wizard, on the "Bundled JRE" step, there is an option "Install only if no other suitable JRE is found".